# Change to custom shipping address during checkout

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Been trying to solve this one for several days without any luck and exhausted all ideas.

I need to programatically change the delivery address of a quote and order during checkout to a custom address.  The customer only enters a billing address (the radio option to enter a different address for delivery is hidden from them).

I created an observer for the following event:

`checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method`

and the function I defined in config.xml fires without any issues.  Now I've tried countless methods from Google and from other posts here to update the shipping address, but they all generate the exception "Please specify a shipping method".

Am I missing something obvious, is there way anyway I can create a custom delivery address in the event above?  Hope someone can help.

Comment: Post some code to show how you're updating the shipping address. Perhaps you've changing the address, but not giving it a shipping method.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of listening on checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method, listen on controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling or controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling. You will need to get rates for the shipping method, for that you will need a shipping address (which in your case was the billing address).

In your observer method, get the quote and shipping address such as:

```
public function saveBillingObserver($observer){

    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

    $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
    $shippingAddress->setStreet(array('123 Main Street'))
       ->setCity('Los Angeles')
       ->setRegionId(12)
       ->setPostcode('90034')
       ->save();
}
```

You can change the shipping address and save it.